# How to write the following MYSQL query in criteria query and hibernate query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

How can I write the criteria query and hibernate query for the following MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM outdatadetail where algorithmno="a0025_d2" and stringno=01 ORDER BY testid desc) sub_query GROUP BY subjectid;
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM outdatadetail where algorithmno='a0025_d2' and stringno=01 ORDER BY testid desc) sub_query GROUP BY subjectid;";
Session session = getSession().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); 
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Thanks, How can we do it the same in criteria query.

Comment: I do not know if we can write such a query like that in criteria

Comment: so can't it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand after reading the documentation and looking at examples you don't need a sub-query to do what you are trying to.

Basically you write 1 query and set a projection to do the grouping.

```
Criteria query = currentSession.createCriteria(OutDataDetail.class);
query.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("subjectid").as("subjectid"));
query.add(Restrictions.eq("algorithmno", "a0025_d2"));
query.add(Restrictions.eq("stringno", "01"));
query.addOrder(Order.desc("testid"));
return query.list();
```

The `Criteria` API by itself is fairly useful. But its real power comes when you start using  classes like `Projection`, `Subqueries`, `Order` etc. in conjunction with your `Criteria`.

If you want to use the `Criteria` API with a sub-query you can do the following:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = currentSession.createCriteria(OutDataDetail.class);
subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("algorithmno", "a0025_d2"));
subquery.add(Restrictions.eq("stringno", "01"));
subquery.addOrder(Order.desc("testid"));

Criteria query = currentSession.createCriteria(OutDataDetail.class);
query.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("subjectid").as("subjectid"));
query.add(Subqueries.exists(subquery);

return query.list();
```

Both implementations should return a list of `OutDataDetail` objects (assuming that's the object you are working with).

DISCLAIMER: I have not tried any of this. It may be that this will not work for you. This answer is written based on my knowledge of working with the `Criteria` API and its associated classes in the past, and the Hibernate 4.1 Manual. You can see the manual section on Projections and grouping [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).